# Flex DataGrid sorting problem - sorts even when no sort necessary

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

Noticed a small sorting problem in a DataGrid we are using.

When a DataGrid column header is clicked, the default alternating ascending/descending sorting takes place. Fine. But when all of the row items in a column are the same, and the column header is clicked, some sorting still takes place, but only for the first click, and this not occur on subsequent clicks.

**Example can be run here:** http://megaswf.com/serve/1103850 
Click the 'In Stock' heading to see the problem.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- dpcontrols/DataGridSort.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                initialize="initDP();" width="550" height="400">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.collections.*;

            private var myDPColl:ArrayCollection;

            // The data source that populates the collection.
            private var myDP:Array = [
                {Artist:'Pavement', Album:'Slanted and Enchanted', 
                    Price:11.99, InStock: true},
                {Artist:'Pavement', Album:'Crooked Rain, Crooked Rain', 
                    Price:10.99, InStock: true},
                {Artist:'Pavement', Album:'Wowee Zowee', 
                    Price:12.99, InStock: true},
                {Artist:'Asphalt', Album:'Brighten the Corners', 
                    Price:11.99, InStock: true},
                {Artist:'Asphalt', Album:'Terror Twilight', 
                    Price:11.99, InStock: true},
                {Artist:'Asphalt', Album:'Buildings Meet the Sky', 
                    Price:14.99, InStock: true},
                {Artist:'Other', Album:'Other', Price:5.99, InStock: true}
            ];

            //Initialize the DataGrid control with sorted data.
            private function initDP():void {                
                myDPColl = new ArrayCollection(myDP);           
                myGrid.dataProvider=myDPColl;               
            }  

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:DataGrid id="myGrid" width="100%" height="213">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn minWidth="120" dataField="Artist" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn minWidth="200" dataField="Album" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn width="75" dataField="Price" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn width="75" dataField="InStock"
                               headerText="In Stock"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>

</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think,this post answers the scenario.

[Flex:Problems in DataGrid default sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893037/flexproblems-in-datagrid-default-sorting)

Comment: Hey thanks, this goes some way to answering the question alright. Searched for ages, but hadnt used the 'default' keyword. Well spotted.